# Unspecified error when submitting posts to Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

As of a few months ago, any attempt I make to post questions or answers to Stack Overflow from my work computers fails. I get a little red box that reads something like "There was a problem with the submission" and that's it - absolutely no further info whatsoever. I have no trouble on other sites, like the math site or the database site.

This happens from both a Linux/Firefox and a Windows/IE platform.

I have seen a few other questions like this here, but it seems that the questioners were dealing with things like image uploads or questions that went beyond the character limit. But I don't have anything like that. I thought it might be something with my company's firewall, but our sysadmins don't have any strong opinions on that and apparently no motivation to investigate.

I have tried disabling the pop up blocker and making sure that JavaScript can run, to no avail. Any ideas what could be going on?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: What are you posting? There have been reports of corporate firewalls overzealously blocking posts with SQL in them.

Comment: No SQL.  I am not trying to do anything other than good ol' ASCII.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. [Screenshot here](http://i893.photobucket.com/albums/ac132/chrylis/stack-overflow-crop_zps8b35695d.png), and the POST is redirecting to `/error?aspxerrorpath=/questions/23477348/answer/submit`.

Comment: That looks much like what I am getting.  Don't know about the redirect.  Thanks for the info.  Anyone out there have any ideas?