# Red popup appeared when I tried to flag a question or an answer

Tags: bug, flags

[image]

I tried Chrome 55.0.2883.87m and Firefox 50.1.0, and extensions are disabled. So far I am able to flag something only through the iPhone app.

Comment: I expect something to be blocked in your network/local setup. Can you open the developer console of Chrome and check for errors( both in the Console and on the Network tab).

Comment: @rene looks like you are right, there's an error 404 "dropped by firewall". Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If strange things like this happen, your best call is to first check if the Developer Console in your browser has any  messages on the Console tab or error conditions on the Network tab. If you can, try a different browser as well.

In [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) pay special attention to the section *what else do I need* at the end of the answer. There are quite a few domains that need to be in working order.

Some countries, ISP's, companies and users run (firewall) software that for various reasons try to protect innocent users from accessing internet resource that they consider harmful. In that effort they might interfere with the content and/or resources needed for Stack Overflow to work correctly.

Here are a few examples of similar reports, some with workarounds:

- [Unspecified error when submitting posts to Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250983/unspecified-error-when-submitting-posts-to-stack-overflow)
- [Use of ajax.googleapis.com not China friendly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258288/use-of-ajax-googleapis-com-not-china-friendly)
- [Imgur.com blocked, what are my options?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261455/imgur-com-blocked-what-are-my-options/261534#261534)
- [Cannot log into Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274348/cannot-log-into-stack-overflow)
- [An error occurred submitting the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298413/an-error-occurred-submitting-the-answer/298472#298472)
- [Asking an SQL Question Appears to Cause Internet Connection Loss](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340068/asking-an-sql-question-appears-to-cause-internet-connection-loss/340221#340221)